# Using Jenkins on CentOS6.4. Can't start listener on port 443. Any hint why

Tags: java, ssl, https, jenkins, centos

Installed the latest Jenkins (1.534) on a fresh CentOS6.4.

Modified the /etc/init.d/jenkins and /etc/sysconfig/Jenkins for the additional parameters 'httpsKeyStore' and 'httpsKeyStorePassword'. Then set 'JENKINS_HTTP_PORT=-1'.
As well I disabled the AJP port (setting it to '-1' too).
Then configuring the HTTPS settings ...

E.g. setting the 'JENKINS_HTTPS_PORT=8181'. And now starting:

'# service jenkins start'

```
=> everything works fine !!!
```

BUT: If I now want to to run Jenkins on default HTTPS port '443' => 'JENKINS_HTTPS_PORT=443', the Jenkins start fails with Java exceptions from winstone.logger ... as if something else would already allocate the port 443 !??

However, looking at at which ports the system is listening (with '# ss -l') I don't see any listener on that port! The system has no apache (or similar) installed (nor started) which would block this port.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ports under 1024 are reserved on a Linux system. Only root users can use them.

This doesn't mean that you should run your server as the root user (it's a good thing to separate the users). However, you'll have to run it on a port above this limit.

To make your system listen on port 443, the traditional way would be:

- Use a reverse-proxy (in which case you're not necessarily going to use your Java server itself via HTTPS, but via HTTP, and have the reverse-proxy handle the SSL/TLS connection).
- Use a firewall rule to redirect port 443 to the actual port internally.

You can check this document, for example: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/setting-port80-access.html

Comment: yeah, I have to admit, that didn't think about that aspect ... embarassing but true (had to work lately too much in the M$ world, where this didn't pose any problem, so didn't think about such :)